# Как сделать циклическую программу?

Tags: java, for, scanner

У меня не получается сделать циклическую программу. Само сравнение получается с if а дальше никак

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cerf {
    public static void Heard() {
        System.out.println("Программа-цикл");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    }
    static double inputNumber(String caption) {
        System.out.print(caption);
        Scanner sc = new
                Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextDouble();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Heard();
        double n1 = inputNumber("Русский:");
        int c = 0;
        double n2 = inputNumber("Математика:");
        int q = 0;
        double n3 = inputNumber("Физика:");
        int w = 0;
    
        if (n1>=4)
        if (n2>=4)  
        if (n3>=4) {
            System.out.println("Поступил");
            }
        if (n1<4)
        if (n2<4)
        if (n3<4){
            System.out.println("Непоступил :O");
        }
         if (n1>1 || n1>4)
         if (n2>1 || n2>4)
         if (n3>1 || n3>4){
            System.out.println("Не поступил :0");
        }
    
        
        }
    }
```

Вот так я сделал, но нужно чтобы количество учеников водилось с клавиатуры. И выводилось сколько именно поступило.

Comment: Возможно надо делать через for ?

Comment: Чтобы сделать цикл, нужно использовать `for` или `while`. Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, что конкретно у вас не получилось сделать? Не видно попыток применения `for` или `while`. [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1472319/edit) ваш вопрос и напишите, что конкретно вызвало трудности.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать циклическую программу, нужно написать цикл `for` или `while`. Для бесконечного цикла подойдет цикл `while` с условием `true`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Русский: ");
        if (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) break;
        double a = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Математика: ");
        if (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) break;
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Сумма: " + (a + b));
    }
}
```

Чтобы прервать цикл и выйти из программы, отправьте команду [`EOF`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF) (В Unix и Linux это <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, а в Windows — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).